# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ValidatorFactory after upgrading Hibernate dependencies

Tags: java, hibernate, gradle

I just updated my Hibernate dependencies in my gradle build file from:

```
implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.12.Final'
implementation 'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.0.18.Final'
implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:5.4.21.Final'
```

to:

```
implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.5.7.Final'
implementation 'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:7.0.1.Final'
implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:5.5.7.Final'
```

I already saw, that the validation API has been moved from `javax.*` to `jakarta.*` and I guess it has something to do with that. However, I was not able to find out which dependencies are in conflict in this case and what I would have to change to make it compatible.
Can someone help me there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced with same exception. It throws from TypeSafeActivator class

So according to https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/5.5/

> Hibernate ORM 5.5 adds new artifacts with the artifact id suffix
> "-jakarta" like hibernate-core-jakarta.

Comment: Thank you for this. I think my problem was that the hibernate validator version `7.0.1` would only be compatible with the `-jakarta` suffixed artifacts. I solved it by downgrading the validator to the last version that used `javax`.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by adding `'javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final'` to my dependencies. Can anyone explain to me why this is explicitly required? Are parts of the validation API still in the `javax` package?